# Insulated boundary conditions diffusion equation numerical simulation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Suppose that we are applying the finite difference method for the diffusion equation to a 1D rod. Now suppose we have insulated boundary conditions (on both ends). According to http://www.math.toronto.edu/mpugh/Teaching/Mat1062/notes2.pdf

the correct matrix to implement for this would be:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
\ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \mathstrut^{.^{.^{.}}} \\
\dotsc & 1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsc  \\ 
\dotsc & 0 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsc  \\ 
\dotsc & 0 & 0 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dotsc \\ 
\dotsc & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & \dotsc  \\
\dotsc & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -2 & 1 & \dotsc  \\
\mathstrut^{.^{.^{.}}} & \vdots &\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
With top and bottom row equal to $\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 2 & 0 & \dotsc \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}\dotsc & 0 & 2 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$ respectively.

**However**, this matrix does not conserve the total amount of mass. To see this note that the sums of the columns are not 0 for every column. This has a practical effect: when running numerical simulations the total amount of mass changes slightly as the diffusion occurs.

Is there a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

Finite volume methods (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_volume_method) are similar to finite differences but are designed specifically to respect conservation laws.  For equally spaced meshes, the finite volume and finite difference discretisation would be the same except for at the boundaries.

A brief derivation is as follows.  Say you are solving the heat equation with insulating boundary conditions on an interval $[0,L]$:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = -\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}, \qquad q = -k\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}.
$$
Note here the equation has been written explicitly in conservative form, where $q$ is the heat flux.  Imagine discretising the interval into $N$ subintervals or 'control volumes' of width $\delta = L/N$.  Now define the spatial coordinates of the *faces* (or boundaries between the subintervals):
$$
x^{(f)}_j = (j-1)\delta x, \qquad q_j = q(x^{(f)}_j), \qquad j = 1,\ldots, N+1
$$
The insulating boundary conditions are that $q_1 = q_{N+1} = 0$.

Now consider the average value $u_j$ in volume $j$ (note these are *not* the values at the faces; you might think of them approximately as the value at the midpoint of each volume).  By conservation we have
$$
\delta \frac{du_j}{dt} = q_{j+1} - q_j.
$$
The approximation comes from how we compute the fluxes at the interior faces.  A central finite difference gives
$$
q_j \approx -k\left(\frac{u_j - u_{j-1}}{\delta}\right), \qquad j = 2,\ldots,N.
$$
Put all this together and you should find a coefficient matrix that looks as follows:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1' \\u_2' \\ \vdots \\ u_{N-1}' \\ u_N'
\end{bmatrix}
= \frac{k}{\delta^2}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 & \\1 & -2 & 1 \\ & & & \ddots \\ & & & & 1&-2 & 1 \\ &&&&&1&-1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1 \\u_2 \\ \vdots \\ u_{N-1} \\ u_N
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which has the conservation property you seek.

A classical reference for what these days is called finite volume method is the book *Numerical heat transfer and fluid flow* by Patankar.

Comment: Do you know a reference which shows an application of this method for the 1D diffusion equation (with constant coefficient)?

Comment: I've added more detail to the answer (both a reference and a brief derivation).

Comment: Thank you. This is equivalent to what I have done, except I have used a centered finite difference rather than a left-difference and right-difference. Using a centered difference is suppsoed to be better for convergence and accuracy. http://www.math.toronto.edu/mpugh/Teaching/Mat1062/notes2.pdf

Comment: If you are interested: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42920/crank-nicolson-method-with-closed-boundary-conditions

Comment: The method I describe is also based on a central finite difference approximation of the flux (and is 2nd order; I accidentally wrote first order above and have edited).  Note you estimate the flux at the boundary between two volumes using the average values of $u$ on either side of the boundary (hence central difference).

Answer (score 0):

It is important to state that there is no such a thing as conservation of heat. There is conservation of energy. Heat is one of the ways in which you can transfer energy between two systems. In that case, energy is transferred through conduction between each section of the rod.

But it is expected that heat would change slightly between two consecutive points. Heat is proportional to the gradient of temperature. If the rod is long enough to reach thermal equilibrium, the heat exchanged between two points at the same temperature is exactly zero.

Thus, I believe there is nothing wrong with that mathematical model.

Comment: You are correct that there is no such thing as conservation of heat; however, there should still be a total conserved quantity in this system. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Yes, energy should be conserved. According to the First Law of Thermodynamics ΔU = Q + W. That means that the heat transferred within your system results in a variation of its internal energy, i.e., its temperature (assuming no phase transitions, reactions or other funny business). However, I'm puzzled by your edit: why do you believe that matrix does not conserve the mass of the system? The heat equation (Q = -k*A*grad T) does not have anything to do with mass balances.

Comment: The question has little to do with heat. I am actually modeling some diffusion of a chemical species. You can see that the matrix does not conserve mass by noting that the columns do not sum to 0. (Each column describes the mass flow of a given "cell")

Comment: Hmm... okay, I get it. However, if you sum the columns of your matrix, the only columns that do not sum up to zero are the first one and the last one. And those columns do not represent real points in which you would measure concentrations. They are artifacts in order to approximate the derivatives in the end points of the rod. For all the columns where there are actual concentrations, the sum of the columns would be zero, hence the mass would be conserved. I hope that was helpful.